# Стиль выделенного ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, style

Пытаюсь задать свой цвет выделения для `ListBoxItem`. Пробую так:

```
   <ListBox x:Name="AccountListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSteelBlue"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
```

В итоге не выделеный Айтем выглядит как нужно, но выделеный всёравно остаётся стандартным. Что я делаю не так? Гуглю и везде задают так. Причём `BorderThickness` задаётся корректно, а цвета нет.

Comment: вас беспокоит фон выделение при движении мыши или при клике?

Comment: @vitidev, в перспективе нужно будет и при наведении и при выделении. но в данном случае хотя бы при клике.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема цвета при клике. Нужно задать стиль

```
<Style x:Key="SimpleListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Border Name="Border"
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightSteelBlue" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

А для hover есть такой хитрый трюк. Я его использую для DataGrid, но может подойти

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
               Color="#FF0000"/>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```